# Preventing USB Network Adaptor creation in Windows 10

Tags: usb, drive

How to prevent the USB based Network adaptor on Windows 10 ? For example by pugling a specialized USB device in to the USB port, a new Network Adaptor can be created by the hacker on a ATM that runs on Windows 10. How we can prevent such activities ? Blocking Storage USB Drive may be possible. But how to prevent the use of a USB drive to act as Network Adaptor by using a specialize USB device?

Comment: There are several products on the market that can selectively block USB devices to improve security. Is this what you are looking for? Or are you interested in the underlying APIs and SDKs that enable such software?

Comment: I am interested in the underlying APIs and SDKs that can be used to disable or prevent the creation of a New Network Adaptor.

Comment: I'd probably attack it from a USB driver perspective.  Either removing the drivers that those devices use, or adding a new, dummy driver that Windows uses instead.

Comment: It is a security requirement for ATM. The ATM is running on Windows 10 OS. The ATM will have only one Network Adaptor as it need to have an IP to connect to the Backend Servers through Firewall. During a Penetration team, it is found that, a specialized device can be connected to the ATM's USB Port and as a result a Wi-fi network adaptor is created and from a iPAD we could access the ATM by using the new or additional IP. Since it is a security concern, I am trying to find out a way that can prevent the use of the USB drive.